# Jquery datetimepicker cannot set min time

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using [JqueryTimePicker][1]. I am trying to set the minimum time of second date time after selecting the first date time. But this is not working.

```
$('#from').datetimepicker({
    minDate:0,
    format: 'd-m-Y / g:i a',
    formatDate: 'd-M-Y',
    formatTime: 'g:i a',
    minTime:'11:00 pm',
    defaultTime:0,
    allowTimes:[
      '10:00 am', '11:00 am', '12:00 am',
      '01:00 pm', '02:00 pm', '03:00 pm', '04:00 pm',
      '05:00 pm', '06:00 pm', '07:00 pm', '08:00 pm',
      '09:00 pm'
     ],
     onChangeDateTime:function(ct,$i){
        //this is not working
        //actually i wil calculate and set mintime
        $('#to').datetimepicker({minTime:'11:00 am'});

     }
});
$('#to').datetimepicker({
    minDate:0,
    format: 'd-m-Y / g:i a',
    formatDate: 'd-M-Y',
    formatTime: 'g:i a',
    allowTimes:[
      '10:00 am', '11:00 am', '12:00 am',
      '01:00 pm', '02:00 pm', '03:00 pm', '04:00 pm',
      '05:00 pm', '06:00 pm', '07:00 pm', '08:00 pm',
      '09:00 pm'
     ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to init datepicker again, you need to pass option parameter.

Check this:
[jQuery Datetimepicker - change minDateTime and maxDateTime on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14361266/3729466)

Comment: `$('#rdatetime').datetimepicker('option', 'minTime', '11:00 am');` is not working.

Comment: What is rdatetime id now? Maybe you forget to change #rdatetime to #to.

Comment: sorry #rdatetime is #to.  this is just cut paste error here to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use **minDate** fn to change the time, like -

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     format: 'hh:mm A'
  }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $("#EndTime").data("DateTimePicker").minDate($("#StartTime").data("DateTimePicker"));
 });
```